# Determine which checkboxes are checked in a list of checkboxes MVC 5 (editorfor)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, enum-flags

This may have been already answered in another thread, but I can't find a solution... so here it goes.

I have defined an enum with flags:

```
 [Flags]
 public enum InfarctRelatedVessel
 {
     [Description("Left anterior descending")]
     LEFT_ANTERIOR_DESC = 1<<0,
     [Description("Right coronary")]
     RIGHT_CORONARY = 1<<1,
     [Description("Left circumflex")]
     LEFT_CIRCUMFLEX = 1<<2,
     [Description("Left main")]
     LEFT_MAIN = 1<<3,
     [Description("Other")]
     OTHER = 1<<4
 };
```

And it is used by a model with its respective helper.

```
[DisplayName("Infarct related vessel")]
[UIHint("FlagsEnum")]
public InfarctRelatedVessel MyInfarctRelatedVessel { get; set; }
```

The view is rather simple.  I display a list of checkboxes for the vessels property and I have a hidden `div` that I want to display when the checkbox for "other" is checked.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyInfarctRelatedVessel, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyInfarctRelatedVessel)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyInfarctRelatedVessel)

        <input type="hidden" id="InfarctVessels" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="well well-sm" id="DivOtherVessel">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyOtherInfarctRelatedVessel, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyOtherInfarctRelatedVessel)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyOtherInfarctRelatedVessel)
    </div>
</div>
```

I am struggling with a jquery script that will detect when the user checks the "other" checkbox and display the hidden `div`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you require:

```
$("input:checkbox[name='@Html.NameFor(m => m.MyOtherInfarctRelatedVessel)']").change(function(){
    var anyChecked = false;
    $("input:checkbox[name='@Html.NameFor(m => m.MyOtherInfarctRelatedVessel)']").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) anyChecked = true;
    });
    if(anyChecked){
        // show hidden div
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW, I assume you are using Razor and at least MVC4 for the `NameFor` extension method, otherwise you can just hard code the name.

Comment: Thank you.  As you assumed, I am using MVC 5 and razor but I had to resort to hardcode the name :S

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the "check", you can do this:

```
$('#checkBox').click(function () {
    if ($('#checkBox:checked').val() == 'true') {
        $('#div').show();
    }
});
```